# Why am I getting only the last associated record with includes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

For the sake of simplicity, I have a `Course` and a `Student` model, Courses has many Students and Students belongs to a Course (I know it's kinda a stupid example cause a Student can only be associated with 1 Course, but whatever)

I made a scope in the Course model to get the Courses which have more than 'x' number of students:

```
scope :with_more_students_than, -> (students_number) { joins(:students).having("count(course_id) > #{students_number}").group('course_id') }
```

Then in the controller I get the Courses with more than 5 Students:

```
@courses_with_more_than_x_students = Course.with_more_students_than(5).includes(:students)
```

And then I show them:

```
<% @courses_with_more_than_x_students.each_with_index do |course, i| %>
    <h2><%= "#{i + 1} #{course}" %></h2>
    <% course.students.each_with_index do |student, j| %>
        <p><%= "#{j + 1} #{student}" %></p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

With the `.includes(:students)` it only shows the last Student, without it I see every Student of those Courses, why?

Comment: Compare both queries, check them on the log and maybe you'll see a difference. One weird thing I see is that you use `joins` and `includes` on the same query, try using `includes` and `references` instead of `joins`.

Comment: It's the same, even using `includes` and `references` at the `scope` instead of the `joins`, and removing the `includes` at the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@courses_with_more_than_x_students = Course.with_more_students_than(5).preload(:students)
```

We probably have different DB, so it works for me with slightly different scope:

```
scope :with_more_students_than, -> (students_number) {
  joins(:students).having("count(courses.id) > #{students_number}").group('courses.id')
}
```

OR with `students.course_id` column.